# Safari and Chrome, position of rotated text goes haywire

Tags: html, css, rotatetransform

well, I normally find the answer to my questions here but this time I didn't so I will now ask my first one here! :)

I have some rotated text on my page and it is positioned using position:absolute, like below:

```
.rotate-box .rotate-text{
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);   
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    position: absolute;
    left: -45px;
    top: 170px;
}

<div class="rotate-box">
    <span class="rotate-text">Rotated text</span>
</div>
```

This works fine on all browsers (with webkit) except for Safari and Chrome where the text is displayed about 90px lower than in the other browsers.

To prevent this I have added:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
    .rotate-text {top: 80px !important;}
}
```

Now the text is in the correct place in all browsers but this doesn't feel right to me... Am I missing something here?

I hate adding browser exception code, it tends to come back and bite you in the long run... :o

Regards,
Anders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
```

to

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-100px, 16px);
```

As you know, this line is only used by the webkit browsers (Safari, Chrome)

You'll probably have to play around with the exact px figures, but then you can get rid of the extra @media screen tag.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform-origin). Basically, you should be able to do `transform-origin: 0 0;` (with all the prefixes, of course), and it'll hook the rotate to the top left, which sounds like what you want.

Comment: @Anders yes, it does. as visualidiot says, you have to insert the prefix. `-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;` works fine..